# Valid bit value and tag value when having colliding instructions to the same set

Tags: caching, assembly, mips

Doing a preparation task for my upcoming seminar and I got this question here:

> Assume that you have a 32-bit MIPS processor with a direct mapped data cache with the
>   capacity 4096 bytes and a block size of 16 bytes. The cache is initially empty (all valid
>   bits are 0). Which sets of the cache have been updated after that the following program
>   has been executed? For each of the sets, specify the set number, the value of the valid bit,
>   and the tag value of the data cache.

```
1 lui     $t0,0x12ff
2 lw      $t1,0x1240($t0)
3 lw      $t2,0x5aa4($t0)
4 lw      $t3,0x4248($t0)
```

Right so line 2 and 4 have colliding set values (set number 36) where *load word* gets the information. What's confusing me is that *load word* gets information and if the cache is empty there's nothing there to get so I'm a confused what I should answer on the valid bit and the tag value in the question. Or I've just misunderstood the question, not sure. 
Any help is greatly appriciated.

Comment: I'm not really sure if get this right, but in real world the empty cache will detect cache-miss upon such request, and it will fetch the whole 16B line from real memory, making the CPU wait. After it will receive the data from memory, the cache is ready to serve the data, so it will serve them to CPU and unblock the execution of the instruction, which did had cache-miss.  (I'm not sure what that means for your particular question, when two sets collide and how valid bits are calculated/set)

Comment: At (2), the valid bit is clear (i.e. tag is invalid/ignored) so the line is fetched. The line is marked valid and the tag is set. At (4), valid bit is set _but_ tag is different, so line is fetched, and valid bit is [already] set and tag is updated.